# Unable to create a Jbpm process with REST API

Tags: jbpm

I have BPMN having a message start event as shown:

[image]

This message comes in from kafka.

Now I am trying to start a new process instance of the specified BPMN process using REST API which is documented [here](https://www.jbpm.org/api-docs/kie-server/paths.html). Can search for 'Starts a new process instance of a specified process.
'

In the request body, I am having a JSON structure which as follows:
{ "data": { "param1": "123"} }

When doing the POST call to /processes/{process-id}/instances, it returns HTTP 500 and the error description "Unable to create response: There is no start node that matches the trigger none".

Is it due to the request data structure?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

To start a process instance with the API you want to use, you need to add a "Start" node in our business process. The one you are using is not the right node for this API.